# Clicking on a different image button submits the form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, imagebutton

I have encountered a very weird problem. I have a html.beginform with 3 image buttons:

- 2 buttons to add and remove a field
- 1 to submit the form

The buttons are hooked to a javascript events. Now the problem is whenever I click on the add/remove button, it adds/removes a field and immediately after that the form gets submitted and it moves on to the next page. But when I use regular buttons for the add/remove, everything works fine.

It's like the image buttons execute of javascript events, regardless of the button that is clicked.

Javascript code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var numCheck = $('.clonedInputCheck').length;
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);      


        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
        var newElemCheck = $('#inputCheck' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputCheck' + newNum);

        newElem.children(':eq(0)').attr('id', 'extra' + newNum).attr('name', 'extra' + newNum).val('');
        newElemCheck.children(':eq(1)').attr('id', 'checkVerplicht' + newNum).attr('name', 'checkVerplicht' + newNum).val('');

        if (newNum <= 5) {
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#inputCheck' + num).after(newElemCheck);
        }


        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#btnDel').show();

    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
        var priceNum = $('.clonedInput').length;
        $('#input' + num).remove();     
        $('#inputCheck' + num).remove();


        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);


        if (num - 1 == 1) {
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#btnDel').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#btnDel').hide();

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#veldenForm").submit();
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "veldenForm" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


@section Top {
    <h2>1. Kies de nodige velden</h2>
}
<div class="tabel-container">
    <div class="inter-div">
        <div class="velden-tabel">
            <table class="velden">

                @foreach (string var in data)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBox(var)
                            <label for="Naam">@var</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBox("Verplicht" + @var)
                            <label for="Verlpicht">Verplicht veld</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="input1" class="clonedInput">

                            @Html.TextBox("extra1")
                        </div>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div id="inputCheck1" class="clonedInputCheck">
                            @Html.CheckBox("checkVerplicht1")

                            <label for="checkVerplicht1" id="labelVerplicht1">Verplicht veld</label>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div>
    <input type="image" id="btnAdd" src="~/Images/button_add.png" />
    <input type="image" id="btnDel" src="~/Images/button_remove.png" />
</div>

@section Bottom{

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="image" src="~/Images/navigation_right_button.png" />
}


}
```

**EDIT**

Even when I delete the javascript code, so there is no action attached to the add/remove buttons, when clicking them they still navigate to the next page.

Comment: It's not working on JSFiddle because I'm using mvc, so the controller is necessary

Comment: But, you can extract the rendered html and combine that with just the necessary javascript to repeat the problem and put that in a jsfiddle.  It is very difficult to help someone debug a problem when you cannot reproduce it.  And honestly, the action of isolating a problem often ferrets out the solution.

Comment: An input of type image will submit the form. Source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input with the image type functions like a submit button.  You need to cancel the event.  Change your javascript to the following:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
    //all the other stuff you were doing here...
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;    
});
```

Make similar modifications to your delete button click handler.

Comment: You don't need both `.preventDefault()` and `return false`. One of them is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Becuzz and @MelanciaUK! The `return false` did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

to the two input type image you don't want to post back.